# Ffmpeg adds unwanted metadata

Tags: ffmpeg

we use ffmpeg in WooCommerce to give Customers the possibility to listen to a 30sec sample of the MP3 file they'd like to buy, and also to create a full MP3 version

Since 2 days, both the full and the 30sec MP3s have little blips and pings on a regular interval, every 6 seconds in one case.

Nobody has changed anything in the ffmpeg code

I have opened the unconverted MP3 (the "before" version) and the converted MP3 (the "after" version") in a merging tool, Winmerge.

It shows that the 2 files are mostly identical, but there are differences on a regular interval, something is added. It includes a number of hex characters, 2 line breaks and "audio/mpeg". Looks a bit like this:

```
(00)(00)(02)(00)(10)

audio/mpeg(12)€€(08)
```

This happens until the end of the file. The regular rhythm of appearance corresponds to the regular rhythm of the audible blips and pings.

The other big difference is the header. Here, a big chunk is added, with lots of hex charaters and a few words:
ID3, #TSSE, Lavf58.45.100, Info

I have searched for Lavf and found out that it's a part of ffmpeg.

This added data is probably metadata, and I'd like to remove it. What can I do?

Can I remove the metadata? Can I change the encoder?

(I have no real experience in Linux development, I use PHP shell_exec with this:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=4100 -t '.$duration.' out.mp3 -y'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is gone now, just as it came, without telling us anything about its origins. The question is answered. My advice for people with the same problem would be: Wait a while and try again :-)